# Log shipped database server user SID is created automatically

Tags: permissions, log-shipping, logins

We have a production server "prod"  which has a user say 'test' that lets the users connect to the application and  a logon trigger which stops them from connecting to the server through SSMS.

I  logship 'prod' to the 'rep' database and the user 'test' is obviously created in the logshipped database 'rep' during the logshipping. Now the login 'test' does not have any login from server 'rep', But people can still login to the 'rep' server and query the 'rep' db .

I checked with `SUSER_SNAME` and found the `SID` of the user in rep server which I never created and which is not even present in the login names.

Even If I create a new username in the 'prod' db , after logshipping the new user is replicated in the 'rep' server. This is the weirdest thing I have ever seen.

Can some one help please ?

Comment: Logshipping does not ship logins. You have to script them and create them on the DR server.

Comment: @Kin I think that's the discrepancy. Log shipping shouldn't create logins but they are experiencing behavior that suggests a login SID was created/exists.

Comment: @Cowlby Thats not possible unless someone has created that the OP is not aware of (from sql 2000 through 2016 CTP2 - its not possible).

Comment: Is the database a contained database? Actually the user in the database should be an orphant user on the secondary server, try running sp_change_users_login 'report' in the secondary database and you should see a username without a SID for users without login on the secondary server